# iOS - How to save an Image for later use (canvas art app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

**I am creating an app similar to sketches (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tayasui-sketches/id641900855?mt=8)**

I need to know how to save a view/viewcontroller for reuse. (e.g. the user will create some art and want to go back and edit it).

*Thanks in  advance
Neil J*

Comment: Is that your app you're promoting? ;)

Comment: @user623396 haha, no no! I'm using It as an example of functionality.

Comment: You don't really want to save a view controller. You probably want to save the image displayed in the view controller or the strokes the user made to create it.

Comment: You should be trying to save the metadata and recreate the view instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
I didn't word the question too well. 
But what I ended up doing was saving to NSUserDefaults, using a combination of NSData and other stored values :)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a strong pointer to it in somewhere that won't be released. By the way you might keep `UIImage` instead of the view.